# DESC command doesn't show columns properly

Tags: windows, mysql, ssh, windows-10, putty

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQiO5.png)After using DESC command my terminal is full of "-".
My friends when they log into my sql acc see everything properly.
I tried on second desktop, virtual machine and even online putty host on websites.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use `\G` in place of `;` at the end of the statement.

And don't use `DESC`, use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`!